# HTML anchor treating all paths as Relative

Tags: html, anchor, relative-path, absolute-path

I cannot get my website to treat links as absolute paths.
here is my website:

caseyshancock.com

Look under the contact me and note how the two links are being treated as relative addresses.
Instead of

http://www.linkedin.com/pub/casey-hancock/51/98/880

it tries to make it add my domain name before the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using *smart quotes* in your HTML. Use regular `'` or `""`.

```
<p><a href=“mailto:casey.s.hancock@gmail.com”>casey.s.hancock@gmail.com</a></p>
<a href=“http://www.linkedin.com/pub/casey-hancock/51/98/880”>linkedin</a>
```

should be:

```
<p><a href="mailto:casey.s.hancock@gmail.com">casey.s.hancock@gmail.com</a></p>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/casey-hancock/51/98/880">linkedin</a>
```

Comment: Yep that did the trick.  I should've checked that, this is not the first time I've been burned by "smart quotes".